# problem in rendering of color texture using OpenGL ES in android

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

While rendering the color texture on screen i found some unknown behavior of openGL ES.
Here are same code but representation is different.

First code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>

#include <WindowSurface.h>
#include <EGLUtils.h>
#include <android-base/logging.h>

using namespace android;

EGLint majorVersion = 0;
EGLint minorVersion = 0;
EGLContext context;
EGLConfig config;
EGLSurface surface;
EGLint w = 0;
EGLint h = 0;
EGLDisplay dpy;
GLint dim = 0;

bool init()
{
    EGLint configAttribs[] = {
        EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
        EGL_NONE};
    WindowSurface windowSurface;
    EGLNativeWindowType window = windowSurface.getSurface();

    dpy = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    eglInitialize(dpy, &majorVersion, &minorVersion);

    status_t err = EGLUtils::selectConfigForNativeWindow(
        dpy, configAttribs, window, &config);
    if (err)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "couldn't find an EGLConfig matching the screen format\n";
        return false;
    }

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(dpy, config, window, NULL);
    context = eglCreateContext(dpy, config, NULL, NULL);
    eglMakeCurrent(dpy, surface, surface, context);
    eglQuerySurface(dpy, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
    eglQuerySurface(dpy, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);
    dim = w < h ? w : h;

    GLint crop[4] = {0, 4, 4, -4};
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, crop);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexEnvx(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);

    return true;
}
void drawFrame()
{
    // packing is always 4
    uint8_t t8[] = {
        0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x55,
        0xAA, 0xFF, 0xAA, 0xFF,
        0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x55,
        0xAA, 0xFF, 0xAA, 0xFF};

    uint16_t t16[] = {
        0x0000, 0x5555, 0x0000, 0x5555,
        0xAAAA, 0xFFFF, 0xAAAA, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x5555, 0x0000, 0x5555,
        0xAAAA, 0xFFFF, 0xAAAA, 0xFFFF};

    uint32_t t32[] = {
        0xFF000000, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000,
        0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000, 0xFF000000, 0xFF0000FF,
        0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00, 0x00FF00FF, 0xFFFFFF00,
        0xFF000000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF};

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 4, 4, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t8);
    glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, t16);
    glDrawTexiOES(dim / 2, 0, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, t16);
    glDrawTexiOES(0, dim / 2, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t32);
    glDrawTexiOES(dim / 2, dim / 2, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    eglSwapBuffers(dpy, surface);
    sleep(2); // so you have a chance to admire it
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char ** /*argv*/)
{

    init();
    drawFrame();
    return 0;
}
```

Second code:(Same as first one but the init function is not present all initialization is happening in main function).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>

#include <WindowSurface.h>
#include <EGLUtils.h>
#include <android-base/logging.h>

using namespace android;

EGLint majorVersion = 0;
EGLint minorVersion = 0;
EGLContext context;
EGLConfig config;
EGLSurface surface;
EGLint w = 0;
EGLint h = 0;
EGLDisplay dpy;
GLint dim = 0;

void drawFrame()
{
    // packing is always 4
    uint8_t t8[] = {
        0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x55,
        0xAA, 0xFF, 0xAA, 0xFF,
        0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x55,
        0xAA, 0xFF, 0xAA, 0xFF};

    uint16_t t16[] = {
        0x0000, 0x5555, 0x0000, 0x5555,
        0xAAAA, 0xFFFF, 0xAAAA, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x5555, 0x0000, 0x5555,
        0xAAAA, 0xFFFF, 0xAAAA, 0xFFFF};

    uint32_t t32[] = {
        0xFF000000, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000,
        0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000, 0xFF000000, 0xFF0000FF,
        0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00, 0x00FF00FF, 0xFFFFFF00,
        0xFF000000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF};

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 4, 4, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t8);
    glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, t16);
    glDrawTexiOES(dim / 2, 0, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, t16);
    glDrawTexiOES(0, dim / 2, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t32);
    glDrawTexiOES(dim / 2, dim / 2, 0, dim / 2, dim / 2);

    eglSwapBuffers(dpy, surface);
    sleep(2); // so you have a chance to admire it
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char ** /*argv*/)
{
    EGLint configAttribs[] = {
        EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
        EGL_NONE};
    WindowSurface windowSurface;
    EGLNativeWindowType window = windowSurface.getSurface();

    dpy = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    eglInitialize(dpy, &majorVersion, &minorVersion);

    status_t err = EGLUtils::selectConfigForNativeWindow(
        dpy, configAttribs, window, &config);
    if (err)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "couldn't find an EGLConfig matching the screen format\n";
        return false;
    }

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(dpy, config, window, NULL);
    context = eglCreateContext(dpy, config, NULL, NULL);
    eglMakeCurrent(dpy, surface, surface, context);
    eglQuerySurface(dpy, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
    eglQuerySurface(dpy, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);
    dim = w < h ? w : h;

    GLint crop[4] = {0, 4, 4, -4};
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, crop);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexEnvx(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    drawFrame();
    return 0;
}
```

Problem statement:
First program is not rendering the color texture on screen while second program is able to render.

Why only second program is able to render the color texture on screen even the first and second program is same.

Comment: Android does not allow standalone applications written in C/C++ only dynamic libraries. How are you getting the program with a `main` entry-point to run under Android ?

Comment: i am building it as native service

Comment: Just checking - are you developing an Android image and have developer keys ?

Comment: no no, i need to just render an image in android using openglES and C++.
It is just a basic example to understand the openglES in android environment.

Comment: First code destroys the WindowSurface when `init` returns because it is a local variable.

Comment: Thank you so much @user253751, now i understood what i was doing wrong.

Comment: And could you please tell me how i can use eglCreatePbufferSurface instead of using eglCreateWindowSurface?
using same example....

Comment: Hi @user253751 , could you please look at this question as well....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685000/getting-segmentation-fault-while-calling-gltexparameteriv